# Create database fails mdf file already exists but the file isn't there

Tags: sql-server, docker, maven, flyway

I'm running a flyway script to setup a SQL server database on docker. I've already run `mvn clean install` and when I go to run flyway migrate, I get this error:

```
Cannot create file '/var/opt/mssql/data/MyDatabase.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
```

When I navigate to that directory for that docker container, MyDatabase.mdf isn't there. I've triple checked the configuration for the file location and file name. I even changed the flyway variable for my database name to "MyDatabase_Test" and I got this error:

```
Cannot create file '/var/opt/mssql/data/MyDatabase_Test.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
```

Again, the file specified in the error is nowhere to be found. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?